# cmake: retrieve library from git before using in a main cmakelists

Tags: c++, git, cmake

I'm getting Catch library from github via additional cmakelists.txt which is included into main one:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(MyProject)

add_subdirectory(ext/catch)
include_directories(${CATCH_INCLUDE_DIR} ${CXXOPTS_INCLUDE_DIR} src)
...
```

Where CmakeLists.txt for Catch is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.8)
project(catch_builder CXX)
include(ExternalProject)
find_package(Git REQUIRED)

ExternalProject_Add(
    catch
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/philsquared/Catch.git
    TIMEOUT 10
    UPDATE_COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} pull
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
)

# Expose required variable (CATCH_INCLUDE_DIR) to parent scope
ExternalProject_Get_Property(catch source_dir)
set(CATCH_INCLUDE_DIR ${source_dir}/include CACHE INTERNAL "Path to include folder for Catch")
message(${CATCH_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

However, the building of main project is started earlier than Catch will be retrieved from Git.
How to fix this? What is wrong in my cmake script?

Comment: Just make you main project's target dependent from `catch` libary: `add_dependencies(<main_target> catch)`. So your project will be build *after* `catch` library.

Answer (score 2):

I think I had the same problem, what I did is:

- Put AddCatch.cmake (The cmakelist of catch) in the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
  `e.g.: set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")`
- Remove the line: `project(catch_builder CXX)`
- Replace `add_subdirectory(ext/catch)` by  `include(AddCatch)`

And it should work just fine ;)

Comment: I was using your advice for a long time and it worked. But now, I've moved a project to MinGW toolchain and existing cmake works oddly , it doesn't try to clone the project even at build time (and at configure time too). no errors, no messages. just looks like ExternalProject_Add command is not existing in the script. have you any idea why MinGW doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the download performed by `ExternalProject_Add` happens at _build_time, not when CMake is run, so the download won't have happened yet when `add_subdirectory` is called. With just a little bit of work, you can use CMake's `ExternalProject_Add` command to perform the download of Catch from github at CMake/configure time instead of at build time. This then means it will be present when you call `add_subdirectory`. There's an article [here](http://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/) showing how to do this (it uses GoogleTest as the example and it links through to a fully generalised implementation you should be able to use directly for your situation). The general approach is that it creates a small script which is invoked via CMake's script mode to force the ExternalProject_Add call to happen immediately.